# Can't get this video background jquery plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

(noob here)

Been trying to implement [videoBG](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG) to work for a few hours with no luck...

I've looked around stackoverflow, another person had my problem a year ago, but never recieved an answer. I'm not pulling any errors or anything. Do i need the video converted to not just .mp4 but .ogv and .wbm etc. ?

I am testing on chrome

The video doesn't show.

Don't have any hair left to pull out.

Cheers

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.videoBG.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').videoBG({
        position:"fixed",
        zIndex:5,
        mp4:'sunrise.mp4',
        opacity:0.5
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

    hello
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have a couple guesses.  He uses jQuery 1.5.1, you use 1.7.2.  It's probably nothing, but it IS a difference.  Second.  Is "sunrise.mp4" in the same directory at the html file?  It's easy to miss.  Also depending on your editor...  You might want to write it "./sunrise.mp4"

Comment: In what browser are you testing this?

Comment: I am testing it in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I had to have ALL the available formats - .mp4, .ogv, and .webm to work.

I used this excellent free/open-source converter -  [MiroVideoConverter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)